# How to add Sencha Touch to Visual Studio 2013 Apache Cordova App?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, sencha-touch, hybrid-mobile-app

I want add Sencha Touch UI to my existing Visual Studio 2013 Apache Cordova Appliation, Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible since Sencha Touch is just a JS Framework and Cordova just provides a WebView and API for your web app.

Here is the best place to start: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/getting_started/getting_started.html